# getting of strange error while reading pandas column

Tags: python

i have read excel file successfully using following code

```
import  pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data =pd.read_excel("scatter_chart.xlsx",sheet_name="PriceDemand")
```

here is column names

```
    Price      Demand
0  15.535102  44.522736
1  19.894894  35.884521
2  10.604894  55.967183
3  23.017688  31.789269
4  18.465274  45.187925
```

but when i tried following

print(data["Price"])

i got following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dato\PycharmProjects\my_first_python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Price'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dato/PycharmProjects/my_first_python/read_excel_file.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(data["Price"])
  File "C:\Users\Dato\PycharmProjects\my_first_python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Dato\PycharmProjects\my_first_python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Price'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

for Demand it works fine, i really dont understand  error here ,please help me

Comment: You probably got some special characters there - try ```print(data.columns)``` to see how exactly is it phrased.

Comment: Some times **spaces** creep into cell values in **excel files**. You can also try `df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.strip())`

Comment: Index(['Price ', 'Demand'], dtype='object') , here it is

Comment: as i see there is more space, but why? original excel does not have

Comment: it is working now, thanks guys for professional help, wish you health